# Why no article before "Verbindungen" in this sentence?

Tags: article

In the following sentence, why does "Verbindungen" not have any article?

> Moskau übt keine direkte Kontrolle auf die hiesige Kirche aus, unterhält aber enge Verbindungen zu dieser.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because ordinarily you would expect an indefinite article, but since the indefinite article in German has no plural form, it is simply omitted in plural constructions. (This is a general rule.)

*Ich unterhalte eine Verbindung.* / *Ich unterhalte Verbindungen.*

*Er hat eine gute Idee.* / *Er hat gute Ideen.*

---

Further reading:

- [Link](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Artikel/Gebrauch/Ohne.html#Anchor-Unbestimmter-35882)
- https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/372

Comment: Why would you expect an indefinite article in singular?

Comment: @user34255: Because the usage without any article is typically reserved to non-countable things, or to referring to a concept as a whole.